# AmazonDynamoDB exception when using DynamoDB Scan Expression in Java lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I need another pair of eyes regarding this error when trying to search by specific column, in this case `email`:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: ExpressionAttributeValues can only be specified when using expressions: FilterExpression is null (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
```

This is my lambda code:

```
    var eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    eav.put(":email", new AttributeValue().withS(email));

    var scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
            .withFilterExpression("email = :email")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

    return dynamoDBMapper.scan(Test.class, scanExpression);
```

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your problem, this code runs and returns the expected result:

```
public class DynamoDBMappingTest {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String email = "somebody@360works.com";

        final AmazonDynamoDB ddb = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper( ddb );
        
        Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
        eav.put(":email", new AttributeValue().withS(email));

        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                .withFilterExpression("email = :email")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

        final PaginatedScanList<Test> scan = dynamoDBMapper.scan( Test.class, scanExpression );
        scan.forEach( System.out::println );
    }
}
```

This is my data class:

```
@DynamoDBTable( tableName="DbMapperTest" )
public class Test {
    
    public String id;
    
    public String email;
    
    public String firstname;
    
    public String lastname;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( String id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail( String email ) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname( String firstname ) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname( String lastname ) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
                ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```